# ember.js does not work

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I am trying ember.js, but it does not work on my html. I don't know why, but the browser cannot find module handlebars. The html code:

```
<body class="content" id="authorize">
      <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
        <div class='container'>
            {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </script>
        <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='teachers'>
            {{#each}}
                {{#link-to 'teacher' this}}
                    <div class="grid">
                        <img {{bind-attr src='photo'}} />
                        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
                        <p>{{subject}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <img src="./views/divider.png">
                    </div>
                {{/link-to}}
            {{/each}}
        </script>


        <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='teacher'>
            <div class="teacherinfo">
                <p>{{name}}</p>
                <p>{{subject}}</p>
                <img {{bind-attr src='photo'}}>
                <img src="views/button.png">
            </div>
        </script>
  </body>
```

and custom js code(ember):

```
(function(){
  var App=Ember.Application.create({
      LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
    });

    App.TEACHERS =[...];

    App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('teachers');
  this.resource('teacher', { path: '/teachers/:name' });
  });

    App.TeachersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.TEACHERS;
  }
});
App.TeacherRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.TEACHERSfindBy('name', params.name); 
  }
});
})();
```

The Firefox gives such error.

[image]

Thanks for the attention and help:-)And sorry for the huge code

Answer (score 1):

Ember depends on both jQuery and [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). You likely didn't include the Handlebars script in your page. Include that and the error should go away. [Read the guide for more info.](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/obtaining-emberjs-and-dependencies/)

Comment: I'm afraid I've included it (I asked in handlebars.js to alert some message and it did it).